# context_error: The operation is not allowed for the given context

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am trying to create a new campaing using google ads api with php client library. And simply getting this error. I will post whole php code here since I don't really know what this error is about.
The console outputs the following:

```
[2022-02-22T18:00:13.039301+03:00] google-ads.WARNING: Request made: Host: "googleads.googleapis.com", Method: "/google.ads.googleads.v10.services.CampaignBudgetService/MutateCampaignBudgets", CustomerId: 9445807394, RequestId: "ozBYeKzMcMLizUbsO0r8_w", IsFault: 1, FaultMessage: "["The operation is not allowed for the given context."]"
[2022-02-22T18:00:13.042848+03:00] google-ads.NOTICE: Request
-------
Method Name: /google.ads.googleads.v10.services.CampaignBudgetService/MutateCampaignBudgets
Host: googleads.googleapis.com
Headers: {
    "x-goog-api-client": "gl-php\/7.4.27 gccl\/14.0.0 gapic\/14.0.0 gax\/1.11.4 grpc\/1.43.0 rest\/1.11.4",
    "x-goog-request-params": "customer_id=9445807394",
    "developer-token": "REDACTED",
    "login-customer-id": "6165712462"
}
Request:
{"customerId":"9445807394","operations":[{"create":{"name":"Test Budget #2022-02-22T18:00:12.342+03:00","amountMicros":"500000","deliveryMethod":"STANDARD"}}]}

Response
-------
Headers: {
    "request-id": "ozBYeKzMcMLizUbsO0r8_w",
    "date": "Tue, 22 Feb 2022 15:00:12 GMT",
    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
}

Fault
-------
Status code: 3
Details: Request contains an invalid argument.
Failure: {"errors":[{"errorCode":{"contextError":"OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CONTEXT"},"message":"The operation is not allowed for the given context.","location":{"fieldPathElements":[{"fieldName":"operations","index":0}]}}],"requestId":"ozBYeKzMcMLizUbsO0r8_w"}
Request with ID 'ozBYeKzMcMLizUbsO0r8_w' has failed.
Google Ads failure details:
        context_error: The operation is not allowed for the given context
```

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright 2018 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

    namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\BasicOperations;
    
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use GetOpt\GetOpt;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentNames;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\Helper;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V10\GoogleAdsClient;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V10\GoogleAdsClientBuilder;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V10\GoogleAdsException;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Common\ManualCpc;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Enums\AdvertisingChannelTypeEnum\AdvertisingChannelType;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Enums\BudgetDeliveryMethodEnum\BudgetDeliveryMethod;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Enums\CampaignStatusEnum\CampaignStatus;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Errors\GoogleAdsError;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Resources\Campaign;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Resources\Campaign\NetworkSettings;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Resources\CampaignBudget;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Services\CampaignBudgetOperation;
    use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V10\Services\CampaignOperation;
    use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;
    
    /** This example adds new campaigns to an account. */
    class AddCampaigns
    {
        private const CUSTOMER_ID = '9445807394';
        private const NUMBER_OF_CAMPAIGNS_TO_ADD = 2;
    
        public static function main()
        {
            // Either pass the required parameters for this example on the command line, or insert them
            // into the constants above.
            $options = (new ArgumentParser())->parseCommandArguments([
                ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID => GetOpt::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
            ]);
    
            // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
            $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();
    
            // Construct a Google Ads client configured from a properties file and the
            // OAuth2 credentials above.
            $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
                ->fromFile()
                ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
                ->build();
    
            try {
                self::runExample(
                    $googleAdsClient,
                    $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: self::CUSTOMER_ID
                );
            } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
                printf(
                    "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
                    $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
                    PHP_EOL,
                    PHP_EOL
                );
                foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
                    /** @var GoogleAdsError $error */
                    printf(
                        "\t%s: %s%s",
                        $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                        $error->getMessage(),
                        PHP_EOL
                    );
                }
                exit(1);
            } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
                printf(
                    "ApiException was thrown with message '%s'.%s",
                    $apiException->getMessage(),
                    PHP_EOL
                );
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Runs the example.
         *
         * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
         * @param int $customerId the customer ID
         */
        public static function runExample(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
        {
            // Creates a single shared budget to be used by the campaigns added below.
            $budgetResourceName = self::addCampaignBudget($googleAdsClient, $customerId);
    
            // Configures the campaign network options.
            $networkSettings = new NetworkSettings([
                'target_google_search' => true,
                'target_search_network' => true,
                'target_content_network' => false,
                'target_partner_search_network' => false
            ]);
    
            $campaignOperations = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < self::NUMBER_OF_CAMPAIGNS_TO_ADD; $i++) {
                // Creates a campaign.
                // [START add_campaigns_1]
                $campaign = new Campaign([
                    'name' => 'Test #' . Helper::getPrintableDatetime(),
                    'advertising_channel_type' => AdvertisingChannelType::SEARCH,
                    // Recommendation: Set the campaign to PAUSED when creating it to prevent
                    // the ads from immediately serving. Set to ENABLED once you've added
                    // targeting and the ads are ready to serve.
                    'status' => CampaignStatus::PAUSED,
                    // Sets the bidding strategy and budget.
                    'manual_cpc' => new ManualCpc(),
                    'campaign_budget' => $budgetResourceName,
                    // Adds the network settings configured above.
                    'network_settings' => $networkSettings,
                    // Optional: Sets the start and end dates.
                    'start_date' => date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 day')),
                    'end_date' => date('Ymd', strtotime('+1 month'))
                ]);
                // [END add_campaigns_1]
    
                // Creates a campaign operation.
                $campaignOperation = new CampaignOperation();
                $campaignOperation->setCreate($campaign);
                $campaignOperations[] = $campaignOperation;
            }
    
            // Issues a mutate request to add campaigns.
            $campaignServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getCampaignServiceClient();
            $response = $campaignServiceClient->mutateCampaigns($customerId, $campaignOperations);
    
            printf("Added %d campaigns:%s", $response->getResults()->count(), PHP_EOL);
    
            foreach ($response->getResults() as $addedCampaign) {
                /** @var Campaign $addedCampaign */
                print "{$addedCampaign->getResourceName()}" . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Creates a new campaign budget in the specified client account.
         *
         * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
         * @param int $customerId the customer ID
         * @return string the resource name of the newly created budget
         */
        // [START add_campaigns]
        private static function addCampaignBudget(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
        {
            // Creates a campaign budget.
            $budget = new CampaignBudget([
                'name' => 'Test Budget #' . Helper::getPrintableDatetime(),
                'delivery_method' => BudgetDeliveryMethod::STANDARD,
                'amount_micros' => 500000
            ]);
    
            // Creates a campaign budget operation.
            $campaignBudgetOperation = new CampaignBudgetOperation();
            $campaignBudgetOperation->setCreate($budget);
    
            // Issues a mutate request.
            $campaignBudgetServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getCampaignBudgetServiceClient();
            $response = $campaignBudgetServiceClient->mutateCampaignBudgets(
                $customerId,
                [$campaignBudgetOperation]
            );
    
            /** @var CampaignBudget $addedBudget */
            $addedBudget = $response->getResults()[0];
            printf("Added budget named '%s'%s", $addedBudget->getResourceName(), PHP_EOL);
    
            return $addedBudget->getResourceName();
        }
        // [END add_campaigns]
    }
    
    AddCampaigns::main();
```

How to fix this error? Or what is it about?

Comment: From https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/If1zxD7UBmk, make sure that your ID 9445807394 is a customer account with campaigns and not a manager account, and that the client account has been linked to your account.

Comment: Well. That was an answer actually. Here is where I actually scrued up. I created a production manager account. And then I just clicked on my account profile and choose create an other account. And it did created a test manager account. I didn't know that manager can be a test account to. Then I just loged in into test manager account and under settings->subaccount settings created an other account. But could not login there. Because I didn't invite a users to it. For me it is a big surprise that I can invite myself to an account.

Comment: More on that: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7456139?hl=en they just didn't mantioned that you wont be able to login to that account if you wouldn't invite yourself or someone there.